# Single chat and group chat at same time in xmpp

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

In my application my **User to User** single chat is working perfectly.
but if I send the invitation of Room to any User then single chat is not working.

and I didn't attach group chat code in app yet. just send invitation of Room to other user and then creating single chat.

is there anything logically I missed ?

My code for creating and inviting

```
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage * _roomMemory = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc]init];
NSString* roomID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.room",strGlobalRoomNameForLogin];
XMPPJID * roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:roomID];
xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_roomMemory jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];

[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strCureentUserName] history:nil];

//NSLog(@"strCureentUserName %@",strCureentUserName);

//.........inviting the Friend.......
for (int i=0; i<[arrUserName count];i++) {

    NSString *strInviteUserEmalid = [[arrUserName objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"$"];
   // NSLog(@"strInviteUserEmalid %@",strInviteUserEmalid);

    [xmppRoom inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@user",strInviteUserEmalid]] withMessage:@"Come Join me in this room"];
}

[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];

[xmppRoom addDelegate:_roomMemory delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers of invitees, you may be running into "karma" limits on your server.  Try sending the invites slower by adding a timeout.